# When I download file from Box into Google Colab, HTML was is downloaded

Tags: download, google-colaboratory, box

I am trying to download a file (or several files) from Box into Google Colab using "wget". But, what is downloaded looks like a HTML page not the file itself.

I am using the command:

```
!wget https://AAA.box.com/s/mh7xq8lou9ukb5i7lssz0frou554dupb -O script.py
```

Is there a problem with the URL that I am using? I get the URL by opening the file in Box and click "Get shared link".

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to download from sharing link which is a webpage not a direct download link. So It will download the webpage. As a simple trick you can click download in browser and cancel it. Then copy the URL from download and use it with `wget`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean I go to the Download page of Google Chrome and find the URL. When I do so and use WGET in Colab, I get error: "ERROR 404: Not Found"

Comment: @Mohammad This is a temporary solution. The download link is valid only for a limited amount of time. A more permanent solution would be to use the box-sdk